# Functions not available for tiff raster dataset in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, raster-functions

I am using ArcMap (10.4.1) to work on a landcover dataset. The file format of the raster layer is "tif". However, for some reason, many of the functions in Arcmap are not available - for example, all selection tools are grayed out (see screenshot) and when I want to use the "Clip" tool I cannot select my layer as an input feature.
I assume it has something to do with the format of the raster layer, which is why I include a screenshot of the layer properties as well. I have searched google for almost an hour but not found a solution..

[image: screenshot of layer properties]

[image: screenshot showing that I cannot select many features, such as the selection tool]

Comment: The Clip tool under 'Analysis Tools-> Extract-> Clip' is for vector data not raster data.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant select a raster so if all layers are rasters the selection Tools will be greyed out.

Also I Think the clip tool you want is located in Data Management Tools - Raster - Raster Processing - Clip. I belive there are Three Tools called Clip :)

Comment: Ha! I did not know I could not select a raster... But the Clip-tool you pointed out worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Lena The best way to say "Thank you" here is to upvote and accept the answer that works best for you (and to upvote any other answers you find useful).  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)